# Function of function with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

Given the function (simplified example)

`g[En_, k1_] := En^2 *k1`

I have to plug it inside another expression, where `En` is integrated, but `k1` remains as a free variable. The only way I found to do that is

```
fN[function_, k_] :=  NIntegrate[function[En, k]*Exp[-theta*function[En, k]], {theta,0,Pi/2}, {En,1,3}]
fN[g, 0.1]
(*0.921158 *)
```

But in fact I have many functions like `g` that need to undergo the same procedure, some with one, two or three `k` as argument,

```
g2[En_, k1_, k2_] := En^2 *k1/k2 
g3[En_, k1_, k2_, k3_] := En^2 *k1*k2*k3
```

Can the function `fN` be generalised to admit a function with an arbitrary number of arguments `k` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use your definition, replacing the `k_` with `k__`, i.e.

```
fN[function_, k__] :=  NIntegrate[function[En, k]*Exp[-theta*function[En, k]], {theta,0,Pi/2}, {En,1,3}]
```

That way all parameters you pass to `fN` will be passed to your function in `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Thank you, that's a really nice feature I never needed until now